# Simple way to parse XML to an tableview Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

For an iPhone application I need to request data from an online database. I choice to use for an restful web service. Main reason because it will connect to an JAVA server.

I did find a useful wrapper that helps me to get the data but now I need a good workaround to play with the data. The output is XML. If it is better to use JSON or something else please let me know.

In this situation I search in the online database and I only get names back. Like this:

    
        Name 1
        Name 2
        Name 3

The situation is now pretty simple. I know you can choice for NSXMLParser but I little bit hate the way the parser works: didStartElement, didEndElement and foundCharacters.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Maybe you have a link to a website with useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several. If these are fairly small XML documents (as I expect), then you should look at [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) and [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON). If you also want a more full-featured version (including writing XML documents), look at [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/).